# Strange behaviour of simulator & device when adding rightBarButtonItems to a UINavigationItem

Tags: iphone, uinavigationitem, sigabrt, rightbarbuttonitem

In my application I am added two button at right of a UINavigationItem, its working fine on simulator, but when I testing it on device its gives me error of **SIGABRT**, along with `unrecognized selector sent to NSArray`. I tried to add one button at right side, it was added successfully, and works fine on device as well. Here my question is, whats the problem?

I am adding right buttons using following code,

```
NSArray *buttons=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:btnOne,btnTwo,nil]];
myNavItem.rightBarButtonItems=buttons; //Error on device, but works fine on simulator.
```

**Please, point me what is I doing wrong?**
Thanks!

Comment: What is the selector that it's complaining about?

Comment: @PhillipMills, setRightBarButtonItems

Comment: We will need more context for myNavItem and also from where this code runs. Is it in viewDidLoad? Is it in initWithNib.... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `myNavItem` is not an instance of `UINavigationItem`, but rather an instance of `NSArray` (which does not support `setRightBarButtonItems`). Could you show us more lines concerning `myNavItem`?

My suspicion is that myNavItem did not correctly retain the navigation item that it was originally pointing to. And that it points to an NSArray now by coincidence. This error might not occur in a debug setting if all objects are retained indefinitely for better logging.

If this code runs from an instance of a view controller try to use this line instead:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = buttons;
```

On iOS prior to version 5: if you receive `unrecognized selector sent to NSArray` logs there is something wrong with your memory management. The log should read `unrecognized selector sent to UINavigationItem` on iOS prior to iOS 5.

Once the memory issue is fixed you should use a `UIBarButtonItem` with a custom view containing two `UIButtons`.

Comment: FelixLam, thanks for the reply! I read your comment that `Beginning with iOS 5 it is possible to add several bar buttons to the navigation items`. I was tested my app on iOS 4

Comment: FelixLam, thats right!. I tried with custom view, and add it to subview of `UIBarButtonItem`, but I've some programming issues so I need to use the buttons those like `UIBarButtonItems` and not `UIButton`

Comment: If you want to support iOS 4 there is no other clean way of doing it than using a `UIView` with multiple `UIButtons` as subviews and to create a `UIBarButtonItem` with that `UIView` as custom view. You might to create some PNGs as background images for those buttons which may look like default bar button items.  Look here for a tutorial: http://osmorphis.blogspot.de/2009/05/multiple-buttons-on-navigation-bar.html

Comment: In any case I believe that the answer above answered your immediate problem about the strange behavior. The question you are asking now is new (but well covered elsewhere on SO): How to add multiple buttons to a UINavigationItems on iOS 4?

Comment: FelixLam, thats the ultimate solutions! I should try for it. Thanks for continuous help:)

Answer (score 0):

try adding these buttons to a UIBarButtonItem and add UIBarButtonItem to myNavItem like myNavItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;

Comment: Anu, rightBarButtonItem is working fine, but rightBarButtonItems has problems. I added buttons of type UIBarButtonItem only.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line

`NSArray *buttons=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:btnOne,btnTwo,nil]];`

has an extra right bracket at the end. Not sure if this would cause that error but it should cause some error.

Comment: Scott, It was my mistake, but problem isn't this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UISegmentedControl. Check the UICatalog code sample to check its usage in the navigation bar.

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:btn1,btn2,nil]];
   [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
   segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 35);                                                 

 segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle=UISegmentedControlStyleBar;                            
 segmentedControl.momentary = YES;       
 UIBarButtonItem *segmentBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];        
 [segmentedControl release];       
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = segmentBarItem;  
     [segmentBarItem release]; 
 }
```

This is the best way of adding as many number of buttons in your bar as you desire.Hope it gonna help u.
Thanks :)

Comment: Beginning with iOS 5 it is possible to add several bar buttons to the navigation items.

Comment: Nikhil, nice solutions! but can I doing the same with `UIBarButtonItem` instead of simple `UIButtons`. I required to use `UIBarButtonItem`. I am trying for it, but it crashes.

Comment: I want to add `UIBarButtonItem` into segment control.

Comment: H e m a n g:- yes u can add UIBarButtonItem.Above mention code is for the same.Vote up this answer if you like it. :)

Comment: FelixLam:-Yes It is possible.

Comment: @NikhilBansal, I tried for it yesterday only, but unfortunately I couldn't add `UIBarButtonItems` into `UISegmentControl`. If you'll got any solution please edit your answer.